# Is this logically valid?

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-verification

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}.....+\frac{1}{n-1} > ln(n)$$

and so, necessarily, $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}.....+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}.....+\frac{1}{n} > ln(n)$$

assuming that $n \in \mathbb {N}$.

Comment: Yes, if $n>0$ and $a>b$, then $a+n>b$.

Comment: @user2345215 what is it exactly you are implying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine an inequality $$\frac{1}{n}>0.$$ We can add the same quantity on both sides $$\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)+\frac{1}{n}>0+\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)$$

Now we use your first inequality and the transitivity of $>$, which says that if $a>b$ and $b>c$, then $a>c$, where $a:=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)+\frac{1}{n}$, $b:=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)$ and $c:=\ln(n)$.

Answer (score 6):

I think the hidden agenda here is to prove the statement by induction.  If this is true, the inductive hypothesis given in the OP is incorrect, and instead should be 
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}>\ln \color{red}{(n-1)}$$

To build a proper induction, you begin with the above, add $\frac{1}{n}$ to both sides, then try to prove that $$\ln (n-1) + \frac{1}{n}\ge\ln (n)$$